# Displaying Texbox value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a Asp.Net Webform with a textbox. I am trying to display the value of textbox server control value in a text area embedded with some text on button click. I am not sure if its a server control run at server issue or post back issue, The value of text box is not populated in text area. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button2').click(function () {
                $('#test').show();
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Go" />



        <span id="test" style="display: none">
            <textarea id="showTextarea">
    This is new <%=TextBox1.Text %> from web form server control.
    </textarea>
        </span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery,

```
   $(function() {
        $('#Button2').click(function () {
            $('#showTextarea').val($("#TextBox1").val());
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This code will work if your TextBox **has the ID TextBox1** and your text area **has the ID showTextarea** and your button **has the ID Button2**

In ASP.NET webforms, If your controls are in other ASP.NET Controls(like panels etc..), the ids will not be exactly like this. you may need to check the ViewSource to verify that.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a postback issue. jQuery/javascript handles the click and when it returns false it means don't post back.

**Client side**

If you would like to display the value from the textbox without doing anything with it on the server then you should just retrieve the answer and return false (or you can add the event to the function `function(e) {` and then do a `e.preventDefault();` )

```
  $("#Button2").click(function () {
    $("#showTextarea").val("This is new " + $("#TextBox1").val() + " from web form server control");
    $("#test").show();
    return false;
  });
```

**Server side**

If you would like to handle data on the server side you should add a multiline textbox to the aspx-page and setting it to `Visible="False"` by default:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="showTextarea" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then the following in code behind:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showTextarea.Visible = true;
    showTextarea.Text = "This is new " + TextBox1.Text + " from web form server control.";
}
```

Comment: I am trying to display code like below snippet with jquery. Any suggestions?  





   <textarea style="height: 172px; width: 637px">
     public class <%=tbxProjName.Text%>ConnectionClass
    {
        public SqlConnection <%=tbxProjName.Text %>Connection()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<%=tbxServerName.Text%>;Initial Catalog=<%=tbxDBName.Text%>;Integrated Security=True");
            return con;
        }
    }
    </textarea>

Comment: If you wan't to show it with jQuery then you cannot retrieve values from forms with ´<% .. %>´, you must get the data from textboxes using ´$("#idOfElement").val()´. See my answer above how you join together static text and dynamic from textboxes.

If your consider your original question answered, then you should  "accept" the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button2').click(function () {
            $('#showTextarea').val('This is new' + $('#TextBox1').val() + ' from web form server control');
            $('#test').show();
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<textarea id="showTextarea">

</textarea>
```